# Control Template that wraps another control in XAML

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, coding-style, custom-controls

I want to create a custom control that extends a built-in control and then has a template that wraps that control with a container?

The C# class:

```cs
class ExtraBorderTextBox : TextBox {}
```

The Xaml:

```xml
<ControlTemplate>
    <Border>
        <TextBox/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

That doesnt' work because the `TextBox` in the control template isn't my custom control, it is a second instance.

I need access to the properties and events on `TextBox`, having a different parent doens't make sense, I would have to replicate all of that in my class.

This is a simplified example; imagine `Border` being replaced with a `ContentControl` that has a 50 line control template for itself. I guess I want something like `ContentPresenter` (like I have in the `ContentControl`), but there isn't anything like a "ControlPresenter". Right? Am I missing something, or am I stuck with replicating my content control for the TextBox, or replicating the `TextBox` behaviour and presentation for my content control?

Thanks.

Update:
There is an answer here that does what I want, which is to copy the default template for System.Windows.Controls.TextBox. This will do what I want; I can insert my container into that. I was hoping that WPF provided a way that is more maintainable to do something like this, something like a adorner/decorator pattern.

Is there any way to make this better in some way? Would using something like Expression Blend make this so that I don't have to hand-edit the XAML pasted in from the webpage?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the default control template as a base and modify it. The default control templates can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx

Comment: I was hoping for something more maintainable, but this may be the best I can do. It seems that you have to totally throw out DRY and SOLID in order to do anything in WPF more that laying out simple controls on a window.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you want to inherit from TextBox, do some overriding, and use that new class in XAML.

If so:

1) declare the xmlns namespace at the top of your file:

```
<UserControl
...
xmlns:local="TheAssemblyWhereExtraBorderTextBoxResides"
...>
```

2) use your custom textbox:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Border>
        <local:ExtraBorderTextBox />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```